# Connecting to RDS service of Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have done everything correctly till the 4th step as mentioned on this page.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/GettingStartedGuide/ConnectToDBInstance.html

But I can not telnet nor ping to the Endpoint server mentioned. What else should I check if I want to connect to this mysql server from another AWS EC2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you haven't setup RDS security group properly. Add the security group of the ec2 from which you want to access RDS, to the RDS security group for that RDS.

By default RDS security group blocks all connections.

Comment: i am having issues with this as well.  i added 'EC2 Security Group' from RDS.  is there anything special i should do to the ec2 security setting?  open a port?

Comment: No you dont have to do anything on the ec2 security group.

Comment: i seem to be connecting from localhost fine, ec2 security port 22 open for SSH  and 3306 sg-xxxxxxx for mySQL.  but on EC2 it is not connecting.

Comment: I think you got it wrong you have to add the ec2 security group to RDS security group.

Comment: if you are are sure that its the correct ec2 sec group then I guess your mysql user doesnt have the proper permission to access from ec2.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, everything appears to be setup correctly, however it is still timing out.